# How to use batch job to add the file "create date" into all the files in a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder that gets a new file added everyday to the folder with the same file name but incremental extension such as .001, .002, .003, etc.  However, if there's no file within the folder it starts at .001 again.

The problem is they are all named the same and if I move them to another folder to archive them it would just overwrite the same file over and over again.  I could create a folder each day with the date with only one file in it, but that seems a bit redundant.

Is there a way to look at the create date of each file and rename it to the create date?

I've gotten this far, but it looks like for this situation I have to use a static file name, how to loop through the entire directory?

```
 SET filename = C:\test.001
 FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
 rename c:\test.001 C:\test_%filedatetime%.txt
 move C:\*.txt C:\archive\
```

Comment: Your title asks for `create date`, but your question asks for `modified date`.  Which do you require?  Please edit your title if it is incorrect.  `Creation date` and `modified date` are two of the dates that a file can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this provides the correct sort order:

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "startfolder=%userprofile%\test"

cd /d "%startfolder%"
for %%a in (*) do (
    for /f "delims=." %%b in ('wmic datafile where "name='%startfolder:\=\\%\\%%~a'" get lastmodified^|find "."') do (
        echo(ren "%startfolder%\%%~a" "%%~b.txt"
    )
)
```

Remove `echo` to get it working.

Comment: Endoro, is it possible for you to explain what you did here?  The batch commands are confusing to me and I'm still in the very beginning stages of learning batch files.  I am trying to modify it to filename + YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
SET $path=The_path_who_contain_the_FILES

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%f IN ('dir "%$path%" /a-d/b') DO (
          SET filedatetime=%%~tf
          move "%%~dpnxf" "C:\archive\test_%filedatetime%.txt")
```

Comment: `SET $path = The_path_who_contain_the_FILES` doesn't work as expected. You set the variable `$path ` (`$path`+space) to the value `_The_path_who_contain_the_FILES` (space+`The_path_who_contain_the_FILES`). You can avoid it with double quotes: `SET "$path=The_path_who_contain_the_FILES"`.

Comment: For some reason the new files do not have the datetime attached to the end.  Endoro's solution seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "targetdir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"

PUSHD "%targetdir%"

FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO (
 SET "timestamp=%%~ta"
 SET "timestamp=!timestamp:/=_!
 SET "timestamp=!timestamp::=_!
 SET "timestamp=!timestamp:.=_!
 SET "timestamp=!timestamp:,=_!
 SET "timestamp=!timestamp: =_!
 ECHO MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~na.!timestamp!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work with any file in the nominated target directory where the name does not include <kbd>!</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The gymnastics around `timestamp` are intende to replace <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> with <kbd>_</kbd> since these are illegal filename characters. <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> are similarly replaced - they're legal but often painful.

If you want the destination filename to be name.003.timestamp, remove the `~na` from the destination name.