# How do I move files to a directory that's the create date of the files in Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

My son received a VTech kids smartwatch for Christmas. The software doesn't automatically download any of the pictures, videos, or voice recordings. It just shows up as a drive under My Computer. I'd like to clear the watch every night and incorporate the files into the rest of our family photos, using the same folder structure. I can do this manually via cut an paste, but I'd like to instead just hook-up the watch and run a batch script.

Source files are in **`E:\DCIM\100VTECH`**.
The target directory for the folders is **`C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch`**.

So, for example, if these are the current files:

```
E:\DCIM\100VTECH\100_0001.JPG - Created 12/25/2014
E:\DCIM\100VTECH\100_0050.AVI - Created 12/26/2014
E:\DCIM\100VTECH\100_0053.JPG - Created 12/26/2014
```

I'd like this to be the result:

```
C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch\2014-12-25\100_0001.JPG
C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch\2014-12-26\100_0050.AVI
C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch\2014-12-26\100_0053.JPG
E:\DCIM\100VTECH\ = empty
```

So far, I've used info from these pages to create a script, but now I'm stuck.
http://itproguru.com/expert/2013/02/how-to-create-filename-variable-with-date-and-time-from-command-cmd-batch-file-for-use-in-creating-unique-filename/
[How to use batch job to add the file "create date" into all the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298312/how-to-use-batch-job-to-add-the-file-create-date-into-all-the-files-in-a-direc)

Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "startfolder=E:\DCIM\100VTECH"
set Stamp=booger
cd /d "%startfolder%"
for %%a in (*) do (
    echo --------------------------------------------------
    echo FileVar IS %%a
    for /f "delims=." %%b in ('wmic datafile where "name='%startfolder:\=\\%\\%%~a'" get lastmodified^|find "."') do (
        echo Temp Is %%~b
        set Stamp=%%b
        echo Stamp IS %Stamp%
        set YearVar=%Stamp:0,4%
        echo YearVar IS %YearVar%
        echo ren "%startfolder%\%%~a" "%%~b.txt"
    )
)
```

I feel like I'm close, but I can't figure out how to parse the %%b String (which is a complete date and time stamp, e.g. "20141225105524". When I try to set %Stamp% and %YearVar%, they don't set!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENableDelayedExpansion
set "startfolder=E:\DCIM\100VTECH"
set Stamp=booger
cd /d "%startfolder%"
for %%a in (*) do (
    echo --------------------------------------------------
    echo FileVar IS %%a
    for /f "delims=." %%b in ('wmic datafile where "name='%startfolder:\=\\%\\%%~a'" get lastmodified^|find "."') do (
        echo Temp Is %%~b
        set "Stamp=%%b"
        echo Stamp IS !Stamp!
        set "YearVar=!Stamp:0,4!"
        echo YearVar IS !YearVar!
        echo ren "%startfolder%\%%~a" "%%~b.txt"

        set "newfol=C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch\!stamp:~0,4!-!stamp:~4,2!-!stamp:~6,2!"
        echo MD "!newfol!" 2>nul
        echo COPY "%startfolder%\%%~a" "!newfol!\%%~nxa"
    )
)
```

Major problem : to access values that are modified withing a block `(a parenthesised series of statements)` - like `for...(block)` you need to `ENabledelayedexpansion` and access the values using `!var!`

Note the use of `set "var=value"` also - this ensures that stray spaces are not included in the value assigned. **Provided** te value of a *string* to be assigned to a variable is all-numeric **and does not start** `0` then `set /a var=value` is fine (note - no quotes).

This should get you started.

The extra I've added into the loop should

first set `newfol` to a destination name format yyyy-mm-dd

Then (echo) make a new destination directory. The `2>nul` suppresses 'already exists` error-messages.

Then (echo) copy the file. The `~`nxa`means "get name and extension from filename`%%a`

I'd suggest you don't try to delete the source files within this procedure (the code to do that would be `del "%startfolder%\%%~a"`) because there may be a problem making the copy and auto-deleting would destroy the original. A safety measure would be (after the copy) `if not errorlevel 1 del "%startfolder%\%%~a"` but nothing beats a manual check - just another batch file to run...

Answer (score 0):

I spent some more time researching and trying some things out, here's the working code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "startfolder=E:\DCIM\100VTECH"
set "targetfolder=C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Watch"
set Stamp=booger
cd /d "%startfolder%"
for %%a in (*) do (
    echo --------------------------------------------------
    echo FileVar IS %%a
    for /f "delims=." %%b in ('wmic datafile where "name='%startfolder:\=\\%\\%%~a'" get lastmodified^|find "."') do (
        echo Temp Is %%~b
        set Stamp=%%~b
        echo Stamp IS !Stamp!
        set YearVar=!Stamp:~0,4!
        echo YearVar IS !YearVar!
        set MonthVar=!Stamp:~4,2!
        echo MonthVar IS !MonthVar!
        set DayVar=!Stamp:~6,2!
        echo DayVar IS !DayVar!
        ROBOCOPY "%startfolder%" "%targetfolder%\!YearVar!-!MonthVar!-!DayVar!" %%a
        echo ROBOCOPY "%startfolder%" "%targetfolder%\!YearVar!-!MonthVar!-!DayVar!" %%a
    )
)
```